# google checkout to accept payments abroad uk

Tags: joomla, google-checkout

I have a google checkout account. But its not accepting payments from abroad UK.
did google checkout can be used to accept payments abroad UK. If that is possible then where does I need to change the setting to accept payments from almost all countries.

I am using google checkout in rock quick cart component of joomla.

Answer (score 1):

From Google's documentation:

> Google Checkout is available to shoppers with billing addresses in a number of locations. Buyers can also ship purchases internationally if the seller offers this option. To see if you can sign up or ship purchases to your location, check the Location: drop-down menu on the [sign-up page](https://checkout.google.com/buyerSignup?signupAgent=sierraAgent&gclid=homepage). Remember, while you may be able to purchase products from Google, like Google Earth, you won't be able to purchase from other sellers offering Google Checkout unless your country is listed.
>
> Don't see your location on the list? We're working to make Google Checkout available as widely as possible, and we look forward to expanding our service to more locations soon.

Chances are that either you or your buyer are not in one of the countries listed. There shouldn't be any additional settings to take foreign payments.

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on the error that is being thrown, both to the customers as well as to the seller (available in Tools > Integration Console).
I can't say whether it applies to your specific problem without having specific details about the error being faced, but usually it shows something like: We do not ship to this location. This happens because you have not configured the shipping options. By default, the regions allowed for shipping are limited to the country for which the merchant account is registered. So you need to explicitly specify that you need to ship internationally. Use the `<world-area/>` tag for this purpose.
Example code:

```
<shipping-methods>
    <merchant-calculated-shipping name="SuperShip International">
        <price currency="USD">14.00</price>
        <address-filters>
            <allowed-areas>
                <world-area/>
            </allowed-areas>
            <excluded-areas>
                <postal-area>
                    <country-code>US</country-code>
                </postal-area>
            </excluded-areas>
        </address-filters>
    </merchant-calculated-shipping>
</shipping-methods>
```

This code allows to ship everywhere in the world except in US.
CAUTION: Do not use `<world-area/>` in `<excluded-areas>` as it will override your `<allowed-areas>` and block all shipping regions.
Reference link: [Troubleshooting Merchant Center and Checkout API Issues](https://developers.google.com/checkout/articles/Troubleshoot_Merchant_Issues)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a US or UK based merchant you can accept international payments.

See this blog post about international shipping:

http://googlecheckoutapi.blogspot.com/2007/04/introducing-international-shipping.html

See this doc about implementing international shipping and taxes:

https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=71391

See this article for troubleshooting international shipping issues, in particular the 'does not ship to' error message:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/articles/Troubleshoot_Merchant_Issues.html